# RPM Build - how to get the path where the RPM package been “rpm -ivh” at shell script running by '%post' macro

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm a newbie in rpm build. and i did my best i can to describe the little complicated question with my amature english...

i have a json(.json) with some code,what the post install script do is to copy the json,and it paste it in some directory. The important thing is json is not a part of rpm.
Is there any macro command in rpm spec file which gives me the path where i do install using rpm -i?

The focus is if i install the rpm in any directory the json which is presented in the same directory as that of rpm should be considered and copied to the directory that i mention in %post

Comment: You don't explain where the JSON is coming from, and if you're talking about _where_ the RPM installed to, you set that when you create the RPM.

Comment: json is independent of rpm. It is believed that the path we install rpm will have json in the  same path. Lets say i have downloaded tar from server. when i untar it will have one rpm and one json.  can you tell me how to set that when creating RPM?

Comment: No, the location of the RPM that is downloaded is independent and cannot be found using official methods. RPMs are by nature independent. For example, if you put it on a yum server, there would not be a file "next to it" to download with it.